# plotting two parts of a splitted string using a non-monospaced font yielding proper spacings (using graphics::text)

Tags: r

I want to split a string (`ab`) in two and plot each part (`a`, `b`) separately using `graphics::text` (the reason is unimportant, but I need to stick to base graphics). This is straightforward with monospaced fonts. However, I run into spacing problems using non-monospaced fonts (see lower right part of the image below, where the text overlaps).

```
ab <- "Escape your\nconcerns - Mind\ntoo focussed"    # full string
a  <- "           \n         - Mind\ntoo focussed"    # part 1
b  <- "Escape your\nconcerns -     \n            "    # part 2

layout(matrix(1:4, 2))
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))

plot(0.5, .5, type="n", yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n")
text(.5, .5, ab, family="mono", cex = 2)
plot(0.5, .5, type="n", yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n")
text(.5, .5, a, col ="red", family="mono", cex = 2)
text(.5, .5, b, col ="blue", family="mono", cex = 2)

plot(0.5, .5, type="n", yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n")
text(.5, .5, ab, cex = 2)
plot(0.5, .5, type="n", yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n")
text(.5, .5, a, col ="red", cex = 2)
text(.5, .5, b, col ="blue", cex = 2)
```

**Any ideas on how to fix this, so it will render proper spacings?**

[image]